# Basic Jquery Slider interval issue

Tags: jquery

In this simple code, the slider does not slide to the correct point (which should be 14 + 12 or 26). Instead it slides to 24.

```
$("#slider").slider({
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 100,
step: 12,
value: 14,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#slider-value").text( ui.value );
};
```

});

Fiddle me : http://jsfiddle.net/slandmann/conyyam1/12/

Answer (score 2):

The "error" is in the `min` value.
Basically, you can't get your `value` (14) with a `step` of 12 from your `min` (0), it' just simple math. To fix this, you need to set a different `step` (2, 7 or 14) or set the `min` to 2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to force it to go to a point that is not allowed.

You have defined a step of `12`. So The slider should never reach any point that is not a multiple of `12`. If you wish to set it to `26`, then you will need to have a finer step that allows this value.

Answer (score 0):

You have requested steps of 12, so I would expect value to snap to multiples of 12 (12, 24, 36, 48...).  In this case, 14 & 26 are not valid values.